# Javascript History can't retrieve value in onpopstate

Tags: javascript, pushstate

Here's my code:

```
function pushState() {

    ...snip... (SelectedMenuID has a value of 8)

    var stateObj = { selectedMenu: SelectedMenuID };
    history.pushState(stateObj, "The title to use", path);
}

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if (event.state != null) {
        alert(event.state.selectedMenu);
    }
};
```

A couple of problems:

- Clicking through on each page updates the navigation bar URL fine but does not update the title to `the title to use` as I expect it to
- Pressing back it creates the alert but the value is `undefined` and not `8` as I would expect

Comment: The "title" argument to `.pushState()` is ignored by Firefox, perhaps other browsers too.

Comment: `event.state.selectedMenu` works fine in chrome for me

Comment: @Pointy I'm using Chrome, and expect it to work like the Chrome Webstore works https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/app/8-education

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. According to https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/The-State-of-the-HTML5-History-API there is no browser that currently updates the page title based on the value in `pushState()`. Personally I think this is the correct behavior - the page title should reflect the `<title>` element in the page head.
2. When you call `pushState()` and then use the back-button you aren't going back to the last pushState (which is actually the current state) but to the state before that. In your case it sounds like you are seeing the state at page load which is why selectedMenu is undefined. 
   By the way, it is only Chrome that fires onpopstate to match the initial page load, so in other browsers I wouldn't expect to see the alert.